# tensorflow, tensorflow-quantum, tensorflow-federated latest version compatibility?

Tags: cirq, quantum-neural-network, tfq

I have been working with on some research on tensorflow, tensorflow-quantum and tensorflow-federated and the problem with that is I just can't install those three at my google colab and I tried different version and asked the tensorflow community but there is no answer regarding this topic. So, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's a full working Tensorflow environment available on qBraid Lab. Can't guarantee the same package versions will work for your local OS, but they use `tensorflow==2.7.0`, `tensorflow-quantum==0.7.2`, and `cirq-core==0.13.1`, but don't seem to have `tensorflow-federated` included in that.

Comment: it's really sad I tried several versions for my research and still getting error ... is there any way that I can build package from source code in anaconda?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried using it on qBraid? It's free and it should work

Comment: yes I tried but federated didn't worked.

Comment: Did you try adding federated by installing it in the notebook? Or did that also break? See https://docs.qbraid.com/en/latest/lab/environments.html#install-new-package

Comment: Nah it doesn't install ....